# SSH connect through port forwarding with VPN connected

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and noticed that I can SSH connect to the device on the intranet when my VPN is connected (on that same device). Yet when port forwarding is on and I try to connect from the internet it just hangs.

So with the VPN off; SSH over intranet and internet works

With the VPN on on the Ubuntu device; intranet works, but internet doesn't

How could I get this actually works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if you have the same private IP network address segment on both sides, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24. If that is the case you have a routing problem when connected via VPN. Choose another IP segment on one side and leave the other. It should work.